# PHP Variables inside SQL WP Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, content-management-system

I'm using wordpress and i've created some custom functions. They work fine and now I'm at a point of adding sorting into the query.

```
function select_category_events($category, $order)  {
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix."table";
    $sql = $wpdb->get_results("select * from $table_name where category = '" . $category . "' AND  active = '1' ORDER BY '" . $order . "'");
    return $sql;
}
```

If I remove the ORDER BY and just have:

```
$sql = $wpdb->get_results("select * from $table_name where category = '" . $category . "' AND  active = '1'");
```

It works fine. If I replace $order with 'name' or a field to sort by, it works fine, its just when I pass it in using the variable it just ignores it. It still displays results, they are just unsorted. Here is how I'm calling the function.

```
$order = 'name';
$events = select_category_events($category, $order);
```

$category has a valid category, as I've said, it works fine, it's just when the variable is being used for the sort. Is my syntax incorrect, or should I be going about this in a different way?

Comment: Remove the quotes,you want to order by a column,not by a string  `ORDER BY $order`

Comment: Yep! That did it! If you could put that into an answer I'd like to accept it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the quotes,you want to order by a column,not by a string

```
ORDER BY $order
```

Answer (score 0):

No Issue, please modify your query as :-

```
"select * from $table_name where category = '$category'  AND  active = '1' ORDER BY '$order' ";
```

If it is working fine then please mark it as answer and if not then please inform me what are you getting after running this query...

Comment: No dice mate. Not ordering by the variable. I echo'd the variable to check if its not empty and it indeed does have the correct information in it. If I replace '$order' with the data inside the variable it works. Incredibly confusing, it should work.

Comment: But, your full code is work on my machine with my query, please copy the same query and paste it and check it again....

Comment: I did copy the query, EXACTLY as you wrote it. It's not the query that's the problem, it's the variable. If I replace '$order' in your query, with a field to sort by, it works fine. 

If I echo the variable before it's being called, it showed the field I want it to be sorted by. Thanks for your help

Comment: So, your problem is solved or not if yes, then please share your working code again

Comment: No it's not solved. I need to pass a variable into the query. It doesn't work when I do so. If I just use a field to sort by instead of the variable, it sorts correctly. If I use the variable, it doesn't sort at all.

Comment: $sql = $wpdb->get_results("select * from $table_name where category = '$category'  AND  active = '1' ORDER BY '$order' ");

Answer (score 0):

You have to use query like this:-

```
$sql = $wpdb->get_results("select * from $table_name where category = '" . $category . "' AND  active = '1' ORDER BY " . $order);
```